# Absence of insert,delete,details links in ASP.Net Dynamic Data Linq to Sql Web App

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

I created ASP.Net Dynamic Data Linq to Sql Web Application. I added Linq to Sql item into the project and configured the connection between database tables and project successfully.I run the Default.aspx, I see the table name.When I click it, I can only see items in database table, there isn't any delete, insert, details links.How it looks like is:

http://www.deryanurulus.com/Untitled.png

I corrected the lines in Global.asax.cs file like :

```
        DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(DataClasses1DataContext), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

what is missing in my project, why couldn't I see the update links ( delete, insert ) ? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your LinqDataSource in the file DynamicData/PageTemplates/Details.aspx has EnableUpdate = true